# Press Lock (power) button from Flutter App

Tags: android, ios, flutter, locking

I want to have a button that onpress will lock the phone screen just like the power button on phone.
It should work as a lock button.

Which function required on Flutter to do this??

Comment: There is no way to do this on iOS.

Comment: You cannot override the hardware button behavior. However, you can set an onLockListener.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any plugin that can help for this, but it can be achieved through this,

- Write a function (Platform Specific Code), and through `Platform Channel` invoke particular function written in android from flutter, which will lock your device.

See docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).